# Show that $\frac{21}{r}$ spheres can be made by melting a metal cylinder of radius r & altitude 2.24m

Tags: volume, spheres

A solid cylinder of radius r and of altitude 2.24m is heated with any metal wastage & spheres of radius 2r are made. Show that $\frac{21}{r}$ spheres can be made.

I'm really stuck here & even don't know where should I begin, Your hints would be highly appreciated

Many Thanks :)

Comment: Do you know the formula for the volume of a sphere?  You are just asked to compute the volume of the spheres made and divide into the volume of the cylinder. -1

Comment: yes sphere $4 \pi r^3$ and cylinder $ \pi r^2h$ but are you supposed to keep pi or to substitute the value , a demonstration would knidly help

Comment: @user366082 agreed

Comment: The volume of a sphere is $\frac 43 \pi r^3$  I always do the solution algebraically first.  That way the $\pi$s divide out like they should.  Only at the end do I plug in numeric values.  You were given $h$, so what is the problem?

Comment: @Ross Millikan I have figured out the formulas but I'm having trouble dividing can you help kindly please

Answer (score 2):

First shall we calculate the total volume of the cylinder using $\pi r ^2 h$

Substituting

$2.24 \pi r ^2 $

Next the volume of a one sphere $\frac{4}{3} \pi r^3$

$\frac{24}{3} \pi  r^3$

Now you can divide

Comment: Can anyone demonstrate the division

Comment: number = volume cylinder / volume sphere. Haven't calculated it but consider that the given solution could be wrong looking at the numbers